# How to find indexes for certain character in a string VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm beginner with VB.net.

How do I read indexes for certain character in a string? I read an barcode and I get string like this one:

```
3XXX123456-C-AA123456TY-667
```

From that code I should read indexes for character "-" so I can cut the string in parts later in the code.

For example code above:

```
3456-C
6TY-667
```

The length of the string can change (+/- 3 characters). Also the places and count of the hyphens may vary.

So, I'm looking for code which gives me count and position of the hyphens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like `"3XXX123456-C-AA123456TY-667".IndexOf("-"c)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.Splt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
    'a test string
    Dim BCstring As String = "3XXX123456-C-AA123456TY-667"

    'split the string, removing the hyphens
    Dim BCflds() As String = BCstring.Split({"-"c}, StringSplitOptions.None)

    'number of hyphens in the string
    Dim hyphCT As Integer = BCflds.Length - 1

    'look in the debuggers immediate window
    Debug.WriteLine(BCstring)
    'show each field 
    For Each s As String In BCflds
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,5}  {1}", s.Length, s))
    Next

    'or
    Debug.WriteLine(BCstring)
    For idx As Integer = 0 To hyphCT
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,5}  {1}", BCflds(idx).Length, BCflds(idx)))
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need are the parts between hyphens then as suggested by dbasnett use the split method for strings. If by chance you need to know the index positions of the hyphens you can use the first example using Lambda to get the positions which in turn the count give you how many hyphens were located in the string.

When first starting out with .NET it's a good idea to explore the various classes for strings and numerics as there are so many things that some might not expect to find that makes coding easier.

```
Dim barCode As String = "3XXX123456-C-AA123456TY-667"
Dim items = barCode _
    .Select(Function(c, i) New With {.Character = c, .Index = i}) _
    .Where(Function(item) item.Character = "-"c) _
    .ToList

Dim hyphenCount As Integer = items.Count
Console.WriteLine("hyphen count is {0}", hyphenCount)
Console.WriteLine("Indices")
For Each item In items
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", item.Index)
Next

Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Using split")
Dim barCodeParts As String() = barCode.Split("-"c)
For Each code As String In barCodeParts
    Console.WriteLine(code)
Next
```

Comment: glad to see you here.

Comment: Likewise, not sure why it took me so long to sign up here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that'll split your string and allow you to parse through the values.

```
Private Sub TestSplits2Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestSplits2Button.Click
    Try
        Dim testString As String = "3XXX123456-C-AA123456TY-667"
        Dim vals() As String = testString.Split(Convert.ToChar("-"))
        Dim numberOfValues As Integer = vals.GetUpperBound(0)
        For Each testVal As String In vals
            Debug.Print(testVal)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```